# How to Install 10kW FSP Hybrid inverter

Tags: inverter, solar-energy

I have an FSP 10kW inverter which shows a circuit diagram for a separate input from Grid and an output for the urgent load.
My question is what is this output for when I only need the main consumer load and have no urgent load requirement?
Do I leave the output open for the hybrid inverter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is what is this output for when I only need the main consumer load and have no urgent load requirement?

It's for powering important things when there's a power cut.

> Do I leave the output open for the hybrid inverter?

If you have nothing to connect to it, then connect nothing to it.